# how to reset a game board and allow for a new game in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am learning react native and attemping to build a wordle game but with unlimited plays. how can i reset the game while also changing the word to be guessed? The game works properly - just no way to reset the game + randomize the word (only word is 'hello'). how do I go about adding these 2 features? I want to have a View pop-up(?) that replaces the keyboard with 'play again' like this: [image: figma sketch]

```
const NUMBER_OF_TRIES = 6

const copyArray = arr => {
  return [...arr.map(rows => [...rows])]
}

export default function App () {
  const word = 'hello'
  const letters = word.split('')

  const [rows, setRows] = useState(
    new Array(NUMBER_OF_TRIES).fill(new Array(letters.length).fill(''))
  )
  const [curRow, setCurRow] = useState(0)
  const [curCol, setCurCol] = useState(0)
  const [gameState, setGameState] = useState('playing') // playing , won , lost

  useEffect(() => {
    if (curRow > 0) {
      checkGameState()
    }
  }, [curRow])

  const checkGameState = () => {
    if (checkIfWon()) {
      setGameState('won')
      Alert.alert('Hurrah', 'You won!', [
        { text: 'Share', onPress: shareScore }
      ])
    } else if (checkIfLost()) {
      setGameState('lost')
      Alert.alert('You Lose', 'Try again...')
    }
  }

return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar style='light' />
      <Text style={styles.title}>wordle</Text>

      <ScrollView style={styles.map}>
        {rows.map((row, i) => (
          <View key={`row-${i}`} style={styles.row}>
            {row.map((letter, j) => (
              <View
                key={`cell-${i}-${j}`}
                style={[
                  styles.cell,
                  {
                    borderColor: isCellActive(i, j)
                      ? colors.grey
                      : colors.darkgrey,
                    backgroundColor: getCellBGColor(i, j)
                  }
                ]}
              >
                <Text style={styles.cellText}> {letter.toUpperCase()}</Text>
              </View>
            ))}
          </View>
        ))}
      </ScrollView>

      <Keyboard/>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
```

Comment: for the word you could have an array of words and pick a random word from that array for the reset just  create a function that triggers after you click play again and inside of the function you just put the same all the sets with the default values and change the word